# document ready gives wrong selector height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get proper height of my div element, so in code i Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var h = $('.myElement.active').outerHeight(true);
   alert('height:'+h);
   ... // further more code to work with height
}
```

But this element contains lots of images and seems like I got my alert with height lower than it should be because images can't stretch size of that element so fast. If I request height after couple seconds it will fire alert with correct height.

Question: How to get height and run my code with checking is all images been loaded and transitions if there some is done?

Sincerely,

Vitaly.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you should use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 3):

`$(document).ready` gets triggered by the time the DOM tree was successfully built, similar to calling a script at the very end of the `<body>`. At that time, images might still be loading, which means the height cannot be calculated yet.

Once the whole document, including images, is loaded, `window.onload` will be triggered.

```
window.onload = function() { 
   var h = $('.myElement.active').outerHeight(true);
   alert('height:'+h);
   ... // further more code to work with height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `window.onload` this fires after images have been loaded

```
window.onload = function() { 

 var h = $('.myElement.active').outerHeight(true);
   alert('height:'+h);
}
```